# Как организовать общение приложений?

Tags: windows, c#, .net

Создаются два приложения, которые могут общаться между собой. Одно из них - управляющее, другое - управляемое. Как организовать процесс управления? Оптимальны ли такие стандартные методы Windows как:

- пересылка сообщений (WM_USER),
- создание COM-интерфейса,

Или есть нечто более удобное и простое, использующее возможности .NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из статьи [межпроцессовые взаимодействия](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx):

- Буфер обмена
- COM
- Копирование данных
- DDE
- Отображение файлов
- mailslots
- Каналы
- RPC
- Сокеты

В C# достаточно удобно работать с [именованными каналами](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb298714.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

1. .NET ремотинг
2. Именованные каналы
3. Сокеты

Comment: А неименованный канал можно? Приложений-то два (только запускать аккуратно надо)

Comment: имел в виду в общем технологию каналов

Comment: Вместо .net remoting можно использовать более современную технологию WCF

Comment: Не знаю, реализовано это в c# или нет, но я бы посоветовал использовать socketpair().

Answer (score 4):

Можно ещё через WCF. Одно из приложений хостит сервер, другое к нему подключается.